# How can I hide scrollbar of an overflowing div in css without using overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have a div with `overflow:scroll` , scrolling horizontally.
How can I hide scrollbar of the div in css ?

Comment: `overflow:scroll; height:200px`

Comment: When I apply `overflow:hidden` , I can animate the `scrollLeft` . But need additional workout for touch screens to drag the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use webkit.

```
.hiddenscrollbars::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ngt3kt6e/)

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
<div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>

div.scroll {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/zdwf0a0q/